# How to scroll all the content of Scrollviewer in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer

I added textbox control to scrollviewer programmatically in code behind model class,

```
ScrollViewer scrolView = new ScrollViewer(); 
scrolView.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible; 
TextBox objTextBox = new TextBox();
objTextBox.Text = "Test Large String\nTest Large String\nTest Large String\nTest Large String\nTest Large String";
scrolView.Content = objTextBox;
```

Now my scrollviewer is scrolls the content Textbox but not whole text of the textbox.

Please help me What changes require to scroll all text of textbox control in scrollviewer in my above code.

Comment: I debugged my code and I find that scrolView.ScrollableHeight is lesser than objTextBox.ActualHeight...